# Как в Unity изменить параметр объекта при клике на другой объект?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Например, есть две кнопки и при клике на одну из них нужно менять цвет обеим: у одной "правильно", а у другой - "неправильно". Изначально я меняю цвет через `OnMouseButton`, но этот метод срабатывает только на той кнопке, на которую был сделан клик. А как сменить в это же время цвет на другой кнопке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свяжи кнопки между собой (например, добавь каждой свойство "public GameObject secondButton", и в инспекторе прилинкуй кнопки друг к другу), после чего в OnMouseButton события меняй цвет не только "себе", но и прилинкованному "соседу".

Если по-уму - то вместо свойства "вторая кнопка" лучше объединить кнопки каким-либо тэгом, и в обработчике просто менять цвет всем кнопкам "с этим тэгом", чтобы можно было добавить больше двух кнопок в группу, не переписывая при этом код... но это уже по-уму, для начала сделай по-простому :)